# Setting the dropdown value in JSF 2.0 based upon some condition at runtime

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to setting the value in dropdown box in primefaces JSF. I have one datatable in which data is coming from database, upon selection of one row i need to check the value of one column and according to that I need to set the value in drop down.There are two values in drop box ,they are also coming from database.. just i need to set one value according the datatable column value.

Code for my data table

```
<p:dataTable var="patient"  value="#{patientNotes.patientNote}"
                        scrollable="true" scrollHeight="262" rowKey="#{patient.id}"
                        styleClass="mygrid" paginator="true" rows="10"
                        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                        currentPageReportTemplate="(Displaying {startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords}, Page: {currentPage}/{totalPages})"
                        paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                        selection="#{patientNotes.selectedNotes}" selectionMode="single">

                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{patientNotes.onRowSelect}"  />
                        <p:column style="text-align: center" width="180">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Type" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:graphicImage value="../../images/dialog-warning.png" rendered="#{patient.warning == 'Y'}"/>
                            <h:graphicImage  value ="../../images/alert.jpg" rendered="#{patient.alert == 'Y'}" />
                            <h:graphicImage value = "../../images/transaction_flat_16.gif"  rendered="#{patient.creditControl == 'Y'}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Note" width="180">

                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.note}" ></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Created By" width="180">

                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.createdBy}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Date" width="180">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.date}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>


                    </p:dataTable>
```

Here on selection of row i need to check one variable alert if it is "Y" i need to set in dropdown box Alert else Admin.. and these two values ALERT and Admin are in dropdown box coming from database i just need to set them.

Code for dropdown

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" class="inputContainer3" id="paneltype">
                    <span>Type: </span>
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{addNotes.typeSelection}" id="menutype">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel=""
                            itemValue="1" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{addNotes.selectedType}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

Please help me, if you more piece of code plz let me no

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the code in your backing bean here. Is it that it's not working right now or what? What is the scope of your backing bean?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly your concrete problem is. The Facelets code posted so far looks fine at first glance. Only the `update` attribute of your `<p:ajax>` is missing, so effectively you won't get any visual feedback, even though the listener method is properly invoked. Perhaps *that* is your concrete problem?